# how to import csv data from a file

Tags: python

In a directory, I have around 100 files- csv datas. 
How to import them to python? 
I searched and I found:

```
import csv
f = open("imgdata.csv")
r = csv.reader(f)
f.close()
```

but it is not working for a directory. It's not about looking for the files, it's about importing them.

Comment: See the examples in the documentation for reading the contents into Python. You will need another method to open multiple files one by one https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html):

```
import glob
import csv
for f_name in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    with open(f_name) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        # do stuff here
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Solution:

```
import os

directory = os.path.join("c:\\","path")
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for file in files:
       if file.endswith(".csv"):
           f=open(file, 'r')
               #  perform calculation
           f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
import glob

for files in glob.glob("*.csv"):
    #to do --
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a basis, what you're going to want to do is put that into a for loop going through all the filenames in the directory, like so:

```
import os
import csv
dirlist = os.scandir(DIRNAME)
for x in dirlist:
    f = open(str(x)+".csv")     
    r = csv.reader(f)
    f.close()
```